# Auto-incremento en input type date en php con codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, codeigniter, date

¡Hola!

Necesito ayuda para algo que lleva ya un par de días rondando mi cabeza y no logro ver la forma de como siquiera empezar (Lo se, suena pretencioso, pero a todos nos ah pasado alguna vez en esta vida).

Lo que pasa es que tengo 3 input´s de fecha *(fecha1, fecha2 y fecha3)*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ellos quisiera hacer que cuando ponga una fecha en el primer input:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los demás se sumen automáticamente en 3 días y el que le sigue a ese sume 30 días (No que sume 33 días, tendría que ser por separado, sume los 30 días que tiene del input "fecha2" ya que si se modifica este (fecha2), el input "fecha3" debe cambiar a 30 días más). Para simplificar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eh estado viendo la forma de lograr el cometido, y al momento, leí que pudiera funcionar con la **función strtotime** pero no se como quedaría dicha función (Soy nood y trato de aprender dia con dia, mis maestros no me enseñan lo suficiente) espero no sonar egoísta o algo parecido, pero de verdad, quiero aprender mas.

*Estoy trabajando con Bootstrap en codeigniter, para este caso, creo seria mas con JQUERY, no?*

Comment: Pero ésto querés hacerlo a medida que se modifican los inputs? Porque entonces lo conveniente sería hacerlo con javascript.

Comment: Cierto... Eso seria: A medida de poner el 1er input, lo que seria en tiempo real...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use la librería [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) para manipular las fechas.

A medida que tipeas en la `fecha 1` se chequea si el formato de la fecha es válido. Cuando lo es, carga el valor para `fecha 2` y `fecha 3`. Si modificas la `fecha 2` se modifica la `fecha 3`. El problema es que si volvés a tipear en la `fecha 1`, se modifican las otras dos fechas. Por otro lado, no se si tenés que poder modificar la `fecha 3` a mano o no.

Si no cumple exactamente con lo que necesitás, avisame y lo vamos modificando.

```js
$('#fecha1').change(function() {
  var fecha1 = $(this).val();
  var time = moment(fecha1, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
  if (time.isValid()) {
    var fecha2 = time.add(3, 'd');
    $('#fecha2').val(fecha2.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    var fecha3 = fecha2.add(30, 'd');
    $('#fecha3').val(fecha3.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
});

$('#fecha2').change(function() {
  var fecha2 = $(this).val();
  var time = moment(fecha2, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
  if (time.isValid()) {
    var fecha3 = time.add(30, 'd');
    $('#fecha3').val(fecha3.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="fecha1">Fecha 1</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha1" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="fecha2">Fecha 2</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha2" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="fecha3">Fecha 3</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha3" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mil gracias por responder, solo tengo una pequeña duda, veo que los input son de tipo text, hay algún problema si fueran tipo DATE?

Comment: @Dante No, debería ser exactamente lo mismo. Lo importante es que se respete el formato de la fecha `D/M/YYYY` o `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: Lo eh estado intentando pero no me funciona, en el ejemplo que pusiste aqui veo que funciona exelente, pero al ponerlo al proyecto no me da...

Comment: Publicá el código HTML que estás usando. Tenés que respetar los `ID` de los `inputs` que puse yo.

Comment: Lo hice, de echo, los tenia con otro nombre, pero sustituí mi código por el tuyo, Solo para no regarla... el momentjs debe estar en fooder... cierto?

Comment: @Dante Si, lo ideal es que este en el footer. Y jQuery debería estar antes de Bootstrap.

Comment: Listo... ya vi lo que pasa y el porque no me funcionaba: Si yo tecleo manualmente cada dígito, este funciona y hace lo que tiene que hacer, pero, si yo auto completo o pego una fecha, el script no funciona. Y si pongo el input de tipo `date` mucho menos funciona... Esas son las observaciones que pude ver...

Comment: @Dante listo, ahí actualicé para que funcione con type date.

Comment: Eres lo máximo!! Funciona como debe, me quedo leyendo mas sobre `momentjs` para aprender mas y razonar tu lógica me parece estupendo! Mil gracias!!!

Comment: Hola de nuevo, espero no molestar con esto, pero siempre me quedo una duda: ¿Como seria para que por default aparezca la fecha de hoy en `fecha1`?

Comment: @Dante `var hoy = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` devuelve la fecha actual. `$('#fecha1').val(hoy)` se la asigna a `fecha1`, si querés que eso ejecute automáticamente el resto del código, agregale después del `val` `.change()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya queda en mi que vuelva a funcionar, ya muestra la fecha actual, pero no me da los demás valores a menos que lo ponga en manual, pero ahora empieza el trabajo :)

Comment: @Dante pone ese código después del anterior.

Comment: Que nood soy xD gracias... ya quedo :D

Comment: Hola (de nuevo), solo dejare esto por aquí por si te interesara hacer puntos ;) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130932/manejo-de-fechas-con-momentjs-en-php